# Twitter API v1.1 Mentions Timeline getting 403 Forbidden

Tags: twitter

I am using following Mentions Timeline API  : - 
 https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json

I am performing authenticated API call for Mentions and using the application (tokens).
 But, getting 403 Forbidden as response when i call authenticated Mentions API. prior of 14 Jan 2014 this Mentions API was working fine. after that it is returning 403 error.

I am getting response when i call following API authenticated with same application tokens: - 
 https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=XXXXX

Can anyone tell me why i am receiving response - 403 Forbidden for Mentions Timeline only not in other API calls

Thanks,
 Ketan

Answer (score 0):

Jan 14th is the day Twitter API switched to requiring SSL/TLS. This discussion has the details:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

Based on your description, you should check your URLs to ensure they're set to "https://..." instead of "http://...".

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json
is now work endpoint for GET users/show. 
403 Forbidden for Mentions Timeline it error mean invalidate token check authentication it requite oauth.